# Are there any standard for exchanging rules rather than data?

Tags: web-development, database, data

Just out of curiosity. There are many open standards for data exchange, as well as standards for exchanging code (jsonp, for example).

But are there any standards for exchanging formulas/rules, for them to be executed on different platforms?

Comment: Please clarify: what rules do you mean? Business rules, artificial intelligence logic rules, ...?

Comment: formulas - like SQL functions (e.g. IFNULL(a, 0) + 10)

Comment: Howard, I suppose you have answered your own question. You can use SQL **standard** stuff on a variety of platforms provided the **implementations conform to the standard**.

Comment: Rules are just a special kind of data. You just need to package it up somehow, json works, and parse/execute it on the other end.

Comment: jsonp doesn't pass code, it just wraps json to be client-side ajax request friendly until cross domain requests get properly worked out.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between rules and queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Deer Hunter and Justin, current practices are:

- Use DB language and its interpreter
- Wrap rules using standard data exchange format and then interpret.